How to make localStorage reactive in Vue 3
Im trying to hide an element in my navbar with v-if. I saved my fetched boolean in my local storage. This is my first time using Vue and i'm stuck with this for the past 2days and couldnt find a reason why its not working.
<template>
    <router-link v-if="canAccessHistory" to="/activity" class="nav-button" @mouseenter="event => setHover(event, true)" @mouseleave="event => setHover(event, false)">
      <div :class="['nav-button-icon-container', activityActive ? 'nav-button-active' : '']">
        <i :class="['nav-button-icon', 'material-symbols-outlined', activityActive ? 'filled' : '']">history</i>
      </div>
      <p :class="['nav-text', activityActive ? 'text-active' : '']">Logboek</p>
    </router-link>
</template>

<script setup>
canAccessHistory = ref(localStorage.getItem('canAccessHistory'));
</script>

I tried everything and the only time it didnt work is when i use the fetched data. I made sure my api returned a boolean. And also checked it in my js.

Please see [ask], then revise your title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags. Also take the [tour].

LocalStorage is not reactive (by default), which means that Vue won't notice changes.
If you want to make it semi-reactive you could use the useStorage function from the package @vueuse/core.
<script setup>
import { useStorage } from "@vueuse/core";

const saved = useStorage(
  "name-of-localstorage-key",
  "default value if nothing is saved already",
);
</script>

<template>
  <h1>{{ saved ?? "Nothing saved" }}</h1>

  <input v-model="saved" style="color: black" />
</template>

Changing the saved variable in the example above will also change the value in localStorage.
Writing directly to localStorage using localStorage#getItem will NOT change saved.
A more common way would be to manage the global state using Pinia.
You start by creating a store:
// stores/auth/index.js

import { watch, ref } from "vue";
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", () => {
  const canAccessHistory = ref(
    localStorage.getItem("canAccessHistory") === "true",
  );

  watch(canAccessHistory, () =>
    localStorage.setItem("canAccessHistory", canAccessHistory.value.toString()),
  );

  return {
    canAccessHistory,
  };
});

You can then import the store in your component:
<script setup>
import { storeToRefs } from "pinia";
import { ref, watch } from "vue";
import { useAuthStore } from "./auth";

const { canAccessHistory } = storeToRefs(useAuthStore());

function switchValue() {
  const newValue = !canAccessHistory.value;

  canAccessHistory.value = newValue;
}

// Only here to demonstrate
const rawFromLocalStorage = ref(
  localStorage.getItem("canAccessHistory") === "true",
);
watch(canAccessHistory, () => {
  rawFromLocalStorage.value =
    localStorage.getItem("canAccessHistory") === "true";
});
</script>

<template>
  <p>Value in store: {{ canAccessHistory }}</p>

  <p>Value in localStorage: {{ rawFromLocalStorage }}</p>

  <button type="button" @click="switchValue">Switch value</button>
</template>

A working demo can be found here.
If you are not interested in manually updating your localStorage you could use a Pinia plugin like pinia-plugin-persistedstate to do it automatically.

Not sure about what kinda value getting from the local storage, but I assume its Boolean value. Hence, you might need computed for listening to changes made on local storage. More on this refer here.
On your script tag, import the function.
import { computed } from 'vue';

Then to listen to changes in your local storage, refactor your current variable as below:
const canAccessHistory = computed(() => localStorage.getItem('canAccessHistory') === true);

This will ensure Vue to watch for your changes in your local storage value

localStorage is not reactive so that wont work.
